# How to check if an XCTestCase test has failed

Tags: swift, xctest, xctestcase

Is it possible to check within a running test if any of its `XCTAssert`s have failed? I have a test with a few assertions in a row, and I want to add some code afterward to perform a specific action if any of them failed:

```
class testClass : XCTestCase
{
    func testSomething()
    {
        let someComputedValue1 = func1()
        let someComputedValue2 = func2()

        XCTAssertLessThanOrEqual(someComputedValue1, 0.5)
        XCTAssertLessThanOrEqual(someComputedValue2, 0.2)

        if anyOfTheAboveAssertionsFailed {
            performAction()
        }
    }
}
```

The part I'd like tips on is that `anyOfTheAboveAssertionsFailed` condition without duplicating the comparisons to the hard-coded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using your own assertion methods solves the PO's issue, it is cumbersome if you need to use several XCAssert-methods.

Another approach is to override `continueAfterFailure`. If there is no failure the property will not be requested. If there is one, it will.

```
class MyTest: XCTest {
    private var hasFailed = false
    override var continueAfterFailure: Bool {
        get {
            hasFailed = true
            return super.continueAfterFailure
        }
        set {
            super.continueAfterFailure = newValue
        }
    }
    override func tearDown() {
        if hasFailed { performAction() }
        hasFailed = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Noticed there's another API you could override instead for the same effect: `func recordFailure(withDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String, atLine lineNumber: Int, expected: Bool)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course write a new function...

```
func assertLessThanOrEqual(value: Double, limit: Double) -> Bool {
    XCTAssertLessThanOrEqual(value, limit)
    return value <= limit
}
```

And then write your tests like...

```
var allGood = true
allGood = allGood && assertLessThanOrEqual(someComputedValue1, 0.5)
allGood = allGood && assertLessThanOrEqual(someComputedValue2, 0.2)

if !allGood {
    performAction()
}
```